BigQuery unable to split and pivot data
I have a table with concatenated error messages similar to this:



Customer ID
Error messages




1
missing_surname;


2
missing_surname; missing_address;


3
missing_surname; missing_address; missing_tel;



I need to split the error messages so that each error message is on a single row and the customer ID is duplicated if the customer has more than one error.
I've looked at splitting the error messages but that just splits vertically.



Customer ID
Error messages




1
missing_surname;


2
missing_surname;


2
missing_address;


3
missing_surname;


3
missing_address;


3
missing_tel;




What have you tried so far?

I have tried the split() which does what I want but it adds an extra empty line after very customer_id.

I'm guessing you're splitting on the semicolon?  Remove the trailing ; from the original string.  For future reference, including this kind of information in your original post makes it a lot easier for people to help you.

@MBEGUM You can just filter out the empty strings as follows: WHERE error_messages <> '' after splitting.
